# Aligning three minipages with equations side by side

Tags: equations

I'm running into an issue when trying to position three equations side by side. I'm using the minipage function but the problem is that whatever width I pick one of the eqautions is always slighly shifted up or down.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
    \beta^2=1-M^2
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
    \eta=\frac{C_{l_{\alpha}}}{2\pi\beta}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
    F=1.07\left(1+\frac{d}{b}\right)^2
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

That's the code I'm using.

[image: This is the result]

any ideas, please, I'm in quite a rush :(((

Comment: Because the mini pages are aligned by `t`op.

Comment: @Sigur does that mean I should align it by center?

Comment: It would be good, but I'm afraid `minipage` has no such option.

Comment: @campa I have to look into \fbox since I have never used it

Comment: `fbox` simply draw a box around the mini page. So you could see the top edge aligned. Since the pages have different heights the problem appears.

Comment: Do all three need to be numbered?  If so, it might be better to have them on their own line.  If not, there's no need for separate `equation` environments (and in a rush doesn't usually work well on stackexchange).

Comment: @campa THAT DID IT !! thanks so much

Comment: @Sigur - Uh, [c] not only exists, it is the default for minipages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `[b]` instead of `[t]`. – Credits of the amazing @campa